# Where can PTHRED_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP be specified and how does it work?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I found that there's a macro called PTHRED_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP which is somehow given as a value to a mutex so that the mutex does an adaptive spinning, meaning that it spins in the magnitude of an immediate wakeup through the kernel would last. But how do I utilize this configuration-macro to a thread ?

And as I've developed an improved shared readers-writer lock (it needs only one atomic operation at best in contrast to the three operations given in the Wikipedia-solution) with relative writer-priority (further readers are stalled when there's a writer and the readers before are allowed to proceed) which could also make use of adaptive spinning: how is the number of spinning-cycles calculated ?

Answer (score 2):

> I found that there's a macro called PTHRED_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP

Some pthreads implementations provide a macro `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP` (note spelling) that is one of the possible values of the `kind_np` mutex attribute, but neither that attribute nor the macro are [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/pthread.h.html).  It looks like at least BSD and AIX have them, or at least did at one time, but this is not something you should be using in new code.

> But how do I utilize this configuration-macro to a thread ?

You don't.  Even if you are using a pthreads implementation that supports it, this is the value of a *mutex* attribute, not a *thread* attribute.  You obtain a mutex with that attribute value by explicitly requesting it when you initialize the mutex.  It would look something like this:

```
pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int rval;

// Return-value checks omitted for brevity and clarity
rval = pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
rval = pthread_mutexattr_setkind_np(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP);
rval = pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &attr);
```

There are other mutex attributes that you can set in analogous ways, which is one of the reasons I wrote this answer.  Although you should not be using the `kind_np` attribute, you can follow this general model for other mutex attributes.  There are also thread attributes, which work similarly.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but that's only the first part what I asked for.
The second part is how the spin-count is estimated.

Comment: @BonitaMontero, how the spin count is estimated is implementation-specific.  And it's moot, too, because you should not be trying to use this feature.

Comment: The spin-count isn't implementation-defined but adaptive. It's impossible to make it implementation-defined since there are so many hw-platforms with different latencies of the underlying kernel-futex and the spin-count depends on the degree of competition on the futex, so there must be some runtime-estimate on what spin-count might be appropriate.

Comment: I said *how the spin count is estimated* is implementation-specific, not that particular fixed spin counts are defined by implementations.  And it cannot be otherwise, because the feature you are asking about has never been standardized.  You are likely right that the spin count is chosen adaptively by typical implementations, but if that were the answer you are looking for then you wouldn't be asking the question.  The details are implementation specific.

Answer (score 1):

I found the code in the glibc:

That's the "adaptive" mutex locking code of pthread_mutex_lock
in the glibc 2.31:

```
   else if (__builtin_expect (PTHREAD_MUTEX_TYPE (mutex)
              == PTHREAD_MUTEX_ADAPTIVE_NP, 1))
    {
      if (! __is_smp)
    goto simple;

      if (LLL_MUTEX_TRYLOCK (mutex) != 0)
    {
      int cnt = 0;
      int max_cnt = MIN (max_adaptive_count (),
                 mutex->__data.__spins * 2 + 10);
      do
        {
          if (cnt++ >= max_cnt)
        {
          LLL_MUTEX_LOCK (mutex);
          break;
        }
          atomic_spin_nop ();
        }
      while (LLL_MUTEX_TRYLOCK (mutex) != 0);

      mutex->__data.__spins += (cnt - mutex->__data.__spins) / 8;
    }
      assert (mutex->__data.__owner == 0);
    }
```

So the spin count is doubled up to a maximum plus 10 first (system configurable or 1000 if thre's no configuration) and after the locking the difference between the actual spins and the predefined spins divided by 8 is added to the next spin-count.